# Can't insert into Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using:
Ubuntu 17.04
MongoDB 3.6

I've just started learning MongoDB and have run into this problem when trying to insert into a document. I can connect to the database but not insert. Here's the code.

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionUrl = 'MongoDB://localhost:27017/myproject',
sampleCollection = 'chapters';

var chapters = [{
'Title': 'Snow Crash',
'Author': 'Neal Stephenson'
},{
'Title': 'Snow Crash',
'Author': 'Neal Stephenson'
}];

MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  // Get some collection
  var collection = db.collection(sampleCollection);
  collection.insert(chapters,function(error,result){
    //here result will contain an array of records inserted
    if(!error) {
      console.log("Success :"+result.ops.length+" chapters inserted!");
    } else {
      console.log("Some error was encountered!");
    }
    db.close();
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help offered :)

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is so, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mongoClient`. A new and better way for Connection.

For more references see [MongoDB Driver Docs.](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionUrl = 'MongoDB://localhost:27017',
sampleCollection = 'chapters';

var chapters = [{
'Title': 'Snow Crash',
'Author': 'Neal Stephenson'
},{
'Title': 'Snow Crash',
'Author': 'Neal Stephenson'
}];

MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, function(err, client) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  // Get some collection
  var db = client.db('myproject')
  var collection = db.collection(sampleCollection);

  collection.insert(chapters,function(error,result){
    //here result will contain an array of records inserted
    if(!error) {
      console.log("Success :"+result.ops.length+" chapters inserted!");
    } else {
      console.log("Some error was encountered!");
    }
    client.close()
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked a treat! What was wrong though with the original way i was doing it?

Comment: I too wrote code the same way you did. But in some machines and sometimes it caused errors and Docs too not clear for these stuffs. Then Version 1.2 released with this feature helped me.